# Typescript modules: defined is not defined

Tags: typescript

I would appreciate if somebody could give some light on TypeScript 1.8 modules.

I have SomeClass.ts file:

```
export class SomeClass {

}
```

and then, in my app.ts I import SomeClass:

```
import {SomeClass} from "./SomeClass";
var xxx = new SomeClass();
```

Both with AMD and CommonJS module system, ES5 target, I build the app and if I open it in browser I get either "define is not defined" or "require is not defined" error.

Should I install some additional libraries for this to work?

Comment: it should work if you target es5 commonjs.

Comment: you need to actually load the library script in your page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the module system to "amd".
Download [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html) and include it in your HTML.

```
<script data-main="scripts/app" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

Notice the data-main attribute. Its value is the path + module name, in your case "app". 
Requirejs will fetch your module, so you shouldn't include it in another script tag.

Comment: So just to be clear - in case I use typescript modules with import, I will always have to use require, right? Is there a way to compile all the project into single file and use it old-fashioned way? I am using Visual studio, by the way.

Comment: See basarat's answer bellow. Webpack can produce bundle of all your modules after you specify entry module (in your case app.js). If you decide to use webpack, then you don't need requirejs.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I install some additional libraries for this to work?

Yes. However you can easily bundle the library in along with your project. E.g. use `commonjs` (allows you to use npm flawlessly) and then compile with `webpack`.

## More

Quickstart : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try. However I am using Visual studio and would expect to be able to run and compile the project without all this long process. I would also like to be able to get a single file without any dependencies, but I guess this is not possible.

Comment: @zeroin, yes, it is possible. That's exactly what webpack does. One big bundle that contains the dependencies along with your code.

Comment: @zeroin regarding the usage of VS: I advise you to become familiar with **npm**. Its tasks can be run from cmd or addons like [NPM Task Runner](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8f2f2cbc-4da5-43ba-9de2-c9d08ade4941). If you decide to go with webpack, the only command you need to run is `webpack`.